# Adding a variable and DC voltage source LC circuit. How to the Voltage out?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I have the following [image: circuit] I want to find out what the Voltage at the Node(\$V_{total}\$). I know that the capacitor and the inductor isolate the two sources from each other.

This is what I get after doing a Laplace transform:
\$V_{total} = \frac{s^2CV_{drive} + sI(s) +  V_{p}}{Cs^2 + 1}\$
My question is there a way to remove the \$I(s)\$ term and have everything in terms of \$V_{drive}\$ and \$V_P\$?

My working out:

KCL at input port

\$i_c = C\frac{d(V_{total} - v_{drive})}{dt}\$

\$I_l =  \int (V_{total} - V_{p}) dt\$

\$I_{total} = i_c + I_l\$

\$I_{total} = C\frac{d(V_{total} - v_{drive})}{dt} + \int (V_{total} - V_{p}) dt\$

Laplace Transform

\$I(s) = sCV_{total}(s) - sCV_{drive} + V_{total} s^{-1} - V_{p} s^{-1}\$

\$sI(s) = s^2CV_{total}(s) - s^2CV_{drive} + V_{total} - V_{p}\$

We need to solve for \$V_{total}\$

\$V_{total} = \frac{s^2CV_{drive} + sI(s) +  V_{p}}{Cs^2 + 1}\$

Comment: Are you looking for the open circuit Vtotal or the output with a load connected to the output at Vtotal?

Comment: The Open Circuit Vtotal? (i think). Does this mean I have to short both voltage sources and determine the impedence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a formula in electrical networks that one becomes familiar with for the total voltage of a number of individual voltages, each connected by an impedance.
[image]
Sorry about the crude sketch. The familiar formula for the Vt of all the voltages is
[image]
So in your case
[image]
where
[image],
[image],
[image],
[image]
So the output voltage Vt is
[image]
A little algebraic manipulation.
[image]
If you had a load impedance on the output, you would put V3=0, and Z3=load back into the equation and redo the familiar equation.

Comment: Thanks you so much for that.  Is there a name/formula for the very first equation or the way of solving things like this?

Also if there is a third voltage source does the numerator in the first term of the first equation (sum_impedances_except_Z_1) mean the other resistors Z2 and Z3 are in series or parallel?

Comment: Take the sum of Z2 and Z3 for the V1 numerator.  It is neither series nor parallel.  It is a part of a numerical expression that will find the common point voltage.